# Get Admin privileges on working directory

Tags: node.js, powershell

Is there a way in node js to get the admin privileges on the current working directory. I want to do some file operations in ***C:/Program files*** in windows. I am using node-powershell and UAC prompts up for each operations.

```
ps.addCommand(`Start-Process -WindowStyle hidden cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c mkdir "C:\\Program Files\\foo"'`);
```

It is possible to get the admin privilege at the beginning and do all the operations after that?

Comment: If you want to run individual commands you need to elavate the calling node.js process. Otherwise put the commands in a script and invoke that script.

Comment: elavate -> elevate *\*slaps self\**